# In Docker how to keep my conda environment and my code persistent?

Tags: python, docker, conda

I have cloned a project (from a github repository) on a fresh Docker container (created from an Ubuntu image).

I need to install a conda environment (and all the libraries specified in the *yml* installation file, like *cmake*, *pip*, *tensorflow* etc.) in this container. And more importantly, **I need everything that I have added myself to be persistent**.

So, I wanted to use:

```
docker run -d -v myproject_volume:/ myproject_image
```

But, I get this error:

> invalid volume specification: 'myproject_volume:/': invalid mount
> config for type "volume": invalid specification: destination can't be
> '/'

I guess one must mount a more specific container directory on a Docker volume (for a matter of size maybe).

But I want my conda environment as well as the code of my project to stay persistent. Is it possible ? How ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mount over the root of the container. Pick some subfolder like `/workspace`

Then when you're in the container, you will need to specify that the environment is created in that folder rather than any default location.

Alternatively, write your own Dockerfile so that it creates the environment from a `requirements.txt` / `Pipfile` only within the container, when built, rather than mounting it outside into your host. Then use `COPY` command to get your code in the container, rather than use a volume also for it